# How can I open another gui by push button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, python-3.x

I made several gui by qt designer and want to connect them by push button

If I push button in my main gui I want to open the second gui

SecDialog is my second gui and MainWindow is the main gui

what is the problem?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from secdialog import Ui_SecDialog

class SecDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_SecDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleMainWindow)

    def handleMainWindow(self):
        window = SecDialog(self)
        window.show

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()        
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put opening and closing parentheses after `window.show`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from secdialog import Ui_SecDialog

class SecDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_SecDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleMainWindow)

    def handleMainWindow(self):
        window = SecDialog(self)
        window.show() # <-- show is a method, therefore you need parentheses after it to call it

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()        
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```